# When I want add a text to a script in Unity it doesn't accept to add it

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvSdN.jpg)
When I want add a text to a script in Unity it doesn't accept to add it. Help

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: What exactly is the "text" you are trying to drop. Id guess it's a text mesh pro text? If so. That isn't the same as Text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you used the right type. If you created, for example, TextMeshPro in your UI you should use the same type within your script.